# files are printed as [object Object] instead of [object File]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to send uploaded files information from client to the server using **angularjs**.

I have included onchange to the file element to get the list of files as shown below.

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file" ng-file-model="files" multiple
        onchange="angular.element(this).scope().getFiles(this)" />
```

But to show selected files on the webpage and to allow to select the files from multiple directories i'm using ngFileModel directive.
Each time when we choose the File, i'm giving an alert which shows the object as [object File].When clicked on Send button, i'm trying to loop through the files and append the files in FormData object and perform some additional functionality, sample code as shown in below code snippets.

I have tried appending the files using the directive tag "`ngFileModel`" and loop through the files as shown below:

```
for (var i in $scope.filesToUpload) {
         alert("from directive" + $scope.filesToUpload[i]);
              //some logic
            }
```

In the above case, files are printed as `[object Object]` instead of `[object File]`.

Appending files using $scope.files:

```
for (var i in $scope.files) {
         alert("scope.files" + $scope.files[i]);
              // some logic
            }
```

In above case also, files are printed as `[object Object]` instead of `[object File]`. Another issue i saw here is when files are selected (`getFiles(this)` ) from multiple folders and click on send button, only it is storing last selected file information.

Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/ch4fVz7iXmJRPthvCsQt?p=preview

Please see the demo in above link, when user selects the file(single or multiple) i'm printing the object which is showing [object File]. But when clicked on send button , when printed the object in different ways as sown in above code snippets it is printing as [object Object]. I think the culprit is ngFileModel directive but inorder for me to select multiple files from different directives and allow user to delete before sending i need that directive. How to print the file object as  [object File] instead of [object Object].Any inputs?

Comment: Alter the object's `.toString()` method? I can't help but wonder why this is important.

Comment: When i'm passing the file details to the server, if the object is [object Object] it is not reading the file information , but if it is [object File] i can read file details in the server..it is very much required for my scenario..

Comment: The `ng-file-model` directive is not an AngularJS core directive. Avoid using the `ng-` prefix for custom directives. It confuses.

Comment: So you’re asking the Internet to debug a broken program that you wrote. Today is a good day to learn how to debug things for yourself, because StackOverflow is not about to debug your programs for you. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It sounds to me like you're expecting some fancy object type on the server. You're going to have to convert what you get from the client into that type on your server. I can tell you how to get it to print [object File] but I'm pretty sure it won't help you in the long run. :)

Comment: I tried all ways and then raised the question here and i'm pretty sure i'm not asking something without trying..And i'm not asking to debug my broken code..it is object conversion which i could not able to convert...Any inputs would be helpful..